# movl / leal, difference in this case

Tags: assembly, x86

We're just starting out with asm and I'm trying to make sense of my lecturer's code:

```
movl (%esp), %ebx
leal (%esp), %ecx
```

I don't see how these two instructions are different except for the register they operate on.

This first one moves the address pointed by the Stack Pointer into register `BX`.

The second one loads effective address pointed by Stack Pointer into register `CX`.

If I got it right, is there any point in using two different asm instructions, or was the lecturer just trying to show it did the same thing?

Comment: This is a bad example of how to use lea/mov, that's why you're confused.

Comment: @Soapbox: agreed. Also, first description is wrong or at least that's the way I read it: it loads the content at the address pointed to by %esp, not the address.

Answer (score 1):

They are not similar.

```
mov ebx, (esp)
lea ecx, (esp)
```

(in regular assembler, not gas style). The first loads `ebx` with the *contents* of `esp`. The second loads `ecx` with `esp` itself. The similar "regular" expression would have been

```
mov ecx, esp
```

but using `lea` you can immediately add a constant, a register, or both to `ecx`. E.g.,

```
lea ecx, (esp+4*eax+10h)
```

sets `ecx` to `esp + 4*eax + 10h` -- using 'mov', you would have to add these with more instructions.